# In XCode, to create another Target or Project when sharing the same models mapped to Firestore?

Tags: xcode, firebase

I have an iOS client app that uses Firestore as database, so I have a lot of models (structs) mapped to Firestore documents, like below:

```
import FirebaseFirestore

struct Role: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String
    var description: String?
}

struct WorkGroupTemplate: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String        
    var roleIDs: [String]   
}
```

Now I have to build an iPad admin app which also uses the same models in the client app. The admin app will have totally different UI and features but share the same models and Firebase libraries as the client app.

Should I make the iPad admin app a new Target in the same XCode project or it's better to create a different project but put them in the same Workspace?

If using different projects, how to share the model files between the client app and admin app?